# How to use "OnNavigationTo" for C#

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I am a beginner WP7 app programmer. Now, I learn the XAML and C# from App Hub.

So, I try to learn the example from App Hub but my program can't work even I copy the example from App Hub. My program is as below:

```cpp
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
    string msg = "";
    if (NavigationContext.QueryString.TryGetValue("msg", out msg))
        MyTBl.Text = msg;
}
```

I had have the object `MyTB1` but the failed name still appear.
Do I need to defied the object or it's other failed?

Comment: What is the error that you are getting?

Comment: Show an example of how you're Navigating. It's possible you're not properly adding the parameter into the querystring

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you need to have the TextBlock control at the xaml layout of your page with x:Name="MyTB1" or another control, that has Text property. 
Good luck.